# How to understand the calling sequence of Python decorator

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I am confused by the calling sequence of the following code piece.

```
#/usr/bin/python


def decorator_no_args(fn):
    if not callable(fn):
        raise TypeError

    def wrapper():
        return fn()

    print "decorator_no_args"
    return wrapper


@decorator_no_args
def foo_no_args():
    print "foo_no_args"


def decorator_args(* args, **kargs):
    def wrapper0(fn):
        def wrapper1(*args, **kargs):
            return fn(*args, **kargs)
        return wrapper1

    print "decorator_args"
    return wrapper0


@decorator_args(1)
def foo_args(arg0):
    print "foo_args"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo_no_args()
```

The output is:

```
decorator_no_args
decorator_args
foo_no_args
```

Function `decorator_args()` isn't called as you can see above. But why is it recorded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things: decorators are applied *when the function definition is executed*, and the `@expression` syntax takes an *expression*; it is evaluated when decorating.

The line `@decorator_args(1)` calls the `decorator_args()` function, passing in `1` as an argument. The *result* of that call is used as the decorator.

Decorators are really just syntactic sugar, this:

```
@decorator_args(1)
def foo_args(arg0):
    print "foo_args"
```

is really executed as:

```
def foo_args(arg0):
    print "foo_args"
foo_args = decorator_args(1)(foo_args)
```

Note that `decorator_args(1)` **is** called. And it's return value is **called again**, to produce a decorated result.

When you look at `decorator_args()` you see it returns a decorator:

```
def decorator_args(* args, **kargs):
    def wrapper0(fn):
        def wrapper1(*args, **kargs):
            return fn(*args, **kargs)
        return wrapper1

    print "decorator_args"
    return wrapper0
```

`wrapper0` is the real decorator; it is returned when `decorator_args()` is called. `foo_args()` is passed to `wrapper0()` (as the `fn` argument), and the original function is replaced by `wrapper1`.

It doesn't matter at all that `foo_args` is never called; decorators are not applied each time when you call the function, they are only applied once. If you called `foo_no_args()` more than once, the `decorator_no_args` message will not be repeated.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall, decorators are essentially functions that take a function as an argument and return another function (possibly the same). That's funception.

The two first lines of your output (the `decorator_*` ones) come from the functions `foo_no_args` and `foo_args` being *defined*, not *called*.

To better understand, have a look at this snippet:

```
def my_decorator(func):
    def wrap():
        print "Function ran"
        return func()
    print "Function defined"
    return wrap

@my_decorator
def my_function():
    print "my_function"

my_function()
my_function()
my_function()
```

Outputs:

```
Function defined
function ran
my_function
function ran
my_function
function ran
my_function
```